# Error while accessing the core service on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: wcf, tridion

I am getting an error while accessing the core service on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. When I am trying to browse `/webservices/CoreService2011.svc` from IIS server, it shows the following error:

> This collection already contains an address with scheme http.
>   There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.
>   Parameter name: item

Can any one help, how it can be rectified.

Comment: Hi muzimil, could you visit the Tridion StackExchange proposal when you have a minute please? area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion We believe the commitment score requires visits from time to time and so is not including you in "users with > 200 rep" figure. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have multiple hostnames setup for your Tridion CME. Or at least you are trying to connect to your Content Manager (in this case with Core Service) using multiple hostnames.

Can you try the following:

- connect using localhost (obviously when you are local on the server) E.g. http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2011.svc
- If above doesn't work, try looking up what host name is registered in IIS for your SDL Tridion 2011 website (in IIS 7, Right click the website, then choose Edit Bindings...). Try connect to the Core Service using the hostname defined in the website bindings
- If above still doesn't solve it, try editing your web.config under "Tridion_Home\webservices" and add the following node under `configuration / system.ServiceModel`

Node:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
<!-- The attribute "multipleSiteBindingsEnabled" was introduced in .net 4 and removes the need of http module: Tridion.Web.ServiceModel.HttpSvcPortFunneler -->
<!-- For https protocol and/or multiport configuration, uncomment this.
     There should be a <add /> entry for each unique combination of protocol and hostname that is configured in IIS Bindings.
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://hostname:portnumber"/>
        <add prefix="https://hostname"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
-->
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Comment: Thank you very Much. The error was authentication problem. I enable Anonymous Authentication, windows authenetication. Hence it worked.